# How to change the value of select2 without trigger event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a `select2`select element whose value I am setting through jQuery

```
$("#select2").val(elment_id).trigger('change');
```

However, I have already defined an onchange event handler.

```
$('#select2').on('change', function(e) {
//TODO
});
```

I would like to just change(set) the value of `select2` without triggering a change event. Any idea, how to do it?

Comment: Why do yo call `trigger('change')` to change the value? Isn't just `$("#select2").val(elment_id)` enough?

Comment: This doesnt change the value on the select2 element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a special event to refresh it:

```
$("#select2").val(elment_id).trigger('change.select2');
```

From docs:

> It's common for other components to be listening to the change event,
>   or for custom event handlers to be attached that may have side
>   effects. To limit the scope to only notify Select2 of the change, use
>   the .select2 event namespace:
>
> ```
> $('#mySelect2').val('US'); // Change the value or make some change to the internal state
> $('#mySelect2').trigger('change.select2'); // Notify only Select2 of changes
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it. This is really cool feature

Answer (score 1):

You could do with  `Jquery` extension create new prototype like this

```
$.fn.extend({
  Val: function(a) {
    $(this).val(a).trigger('change');
  }
})

$('#select2').Val(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you want to change the value in select element. It depends from other element? If you want to fire event on select element change, but don't want to trigger already defined 'onchange' action, you can give your select next unique class, and build next 'onchange' event for that class. But, as i said previously, i don't know what you want to achieve, and it's hard to say which solution will be the best

Comment: Can you please explain with an example. It is not clear to me. Thanks